# Adding additional information to Highstock point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the ***Highstock*** library (not *Highcharts*) and I'm running into an issue I'm sure can be solved.

I need to add some dynamic information to each point on a series. *Highstock* has a built in `tooltip` that displays limited information about a point `onHover`.

I have tried adding a new property to the point at the time of creation; however, this new property is not available in the `tooltip`.

What's interesting is this exact functionality is available in the *Highcharts* library, but I would like to stick with *Highstock* if at all possible.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/japanick/dWDE6/) showing the desired result in *Highcharts*.

I have started looking around inside the [*Highstock* javascript file](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js) looking for a way to expand the properties of the points that actually get added to the series and *I have had some limited success*.

I have added the property to the block beginning on line `8319` and again on `ll320`. This does seem to work, but only when the chart is zoomed in... very odd.

**Has anyone tried this before, or have some insight on what I may be overlooking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add own custom properties, then in tooltip you have access to them via:

```
this.points[x].point.options.your_property;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/dWDE6/199/

There is only one limitations which you should be aware of: when dataGrouping is affected all points are created as new one, so you don't have access to that custom properties.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to test your answer, but I'm running into a problem... I'm trying to dynamically create the data array and I can't seem to get the chart to read my array when populated with objects. It does however work when I build it with a simple array of arrays... any thoughts?

Comment: Could you upgrade my jsFiddle to reproduce issue?